# Is this move/resize operation safe to perform?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Below are some before and after screenshots of GParted. I simply moved both of the Ubuntu partitions (boot and home) to the left, so that I could resize the home partition (extending it all the way to the right).

The NTFS partition on this drive is not my Windows partition.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: Something bad could always happen. Every one will say that to you. So keep backup, just in case. But in practice, I don't think this could cause any problem. Obviously do that from a live usb and not from the running ubuntu on /dev/sda disk.

Comment: 'safe' is a relative term when mucking with partitions. Always treat partition changes as unsafe, risking total data loss, and backup accordingly before you begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding is GParted safe, see [GParted FAQ - Is It Safe?](https://gparted.org/faq.php#faq-6)

If you move the Linux boot/root partition or Windows boot/C: partition, then you may need to restore the ability to boot.

See [GParted Manual - Fixing Operating System Boot Problems](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-operating-system-boot-problems) and [GParted FAQ - Restore Windows Boot](https://gparted.org/faq.php#faq-14).